# Как написать цикл с разной паузой для каждой команды (Android)?

Tags: java, android, циклы, мобильная-разработка

Есть кнопка при нажатии которой отправляется всего одна команда:

```
bytesToSend = addCRC(new byte[]{0x1, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0 ,0x0, 0x0}); // Команда статус
mPhysicaloid.write(bytesToSend, bytesToSend.length);
```

Не могу понять как мне написать цикл который будет отправлять все вот эти команды:

```
addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 11, 5 ,0, 0});    //10 сек
addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 11, 1 ,0, 0});    //0 сек
addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 0, 5 ,0, 0});      //30 сек
addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 1, 5 ,0, 0});      //5 сек
addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 2, 5 ,0, 0});      //5 сек
addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 3, 5 ,0, 0});      //5 сек
addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 4, 5 ,0, 0});      //5 сек
addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 5, 5 ,0, 0});      //5 сек
addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 6, 5 ,0, 0});      //5 сек
addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 7, 5 ,0, 0});      //5 сек
addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 8, 5 ,0, 0});      //5 сек
```

После каждой команды должна быть пауза (В комментариях указано), значение паузы для каждой команды будет хранится в переменой int

---

**UPD:**
Должно получатся типа как то так:

```
public byte[] MyListComands = new byte[11];

public void onClickWrite(View v) { 
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int TimeOut = 0;
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 11;  i++, Thread.sleep(TimeOut)) {
                    MyListComands[i] = addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 1, 5 ,0, 0});
                    // Тут как я догоняю должно быть то - что в зависимости от значение "i"
                    // будет присваивать новое значение таймеру TimeOut
                    mPhysicaloid.write(MyListComands[i], MyListComands[i].length);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // тут хз что ;(
            }
        }

    }.start();
}
```

Но эта работать не будет, но как же всетаки это сделать ?

Хотя есть чувство что должно быть так:

```
public byte[][] MyListComands = new byte[11][8];
```

Comment: Храните вместе с данными команды и паузу перед/после нее. Отправляете команду, делаете паузу. И так далее пока список не кончится.

Comment: Но как это можно сделать ?
Если не сложно поделитесь ссылкой где можно увидеть как реализовывается данный цикл с паузами

Comment: Можно сделать это ровно так, как я написал. Если у вас сложности - задавайте конкретные вопросы, а не "как это сделать", когда это самое "как" вам в общем уже расписали.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов обновил, вопрос, помогите правильно составить цикл

Comment: про `MyListComands` чувство верное, можно данные объединить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо, за подсказку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что у вас концепцию **паузы после** выполнение можно заменить на **задержку перед** выполнением. Если это так, тогда можно использовать пакет *java.util.concurrent*.

```
ScheduledExecutorService mExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

public void onClickWrite(View v) { 

    mExecutor.schedule(getRunnable(addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 11, 5 ,0, 0})), 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //10
    mExecutor.schedule(getRunnable(addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 11, 1 ,0, 0})), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //0
    mExecutor.schedule(getRunnable(addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 0, 5 ,0, 0})), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //30
    mExecutor.schedule(getRunnable(addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 1, 5 ,0, 0})), 40, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //5
    mExecutor.schedule(getRunnable(addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 2, 5 ,0, 0})), 45, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //5
    mExecutor.schedule(getRunnable(addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 3, 5 ,0, 0})), 50, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //5
    mExecutor.schedule(getRunnable(addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 4, 5 ,0, 0})), 55, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //5
    mExecutor.schedule(getRunnable(addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 5, 5 ,0, 0})), 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //5
    mExecutor.schedule(getRunnable(addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 6, 5 ,0, 0})), 65, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //5
    mExecutor.schedule(getRunnable(addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 7, 5 ,0, 0})), 70, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //5
    mExecutor.schedule(getRunnable(addCRC(new byte[]{1, 0x5, 8, 5 ,0, 0})), 75, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //5

}

public Runnable getRunnable(final byte[] data){
    return new Runnable(){
        @Override public void run(){
            //что-то сделать с задержкой
        }
    }
}
```

Выглядит немного грубо, но на этой основе можно сделать какой-то класс-обертку, который будет использовать весь этот принцип с `ScheduledExecutor` 
и будет иметь методы, типа

```
public void execute(Runnable runable, int pause)
```

И как-то считать задежки через эти паузы. Но это если позарез нужен красивый АПИ для пауз.